# What should I encrypt on MySQL if there is sensitive information?

Tags: mysql, encryption, aes

I am making an application where there is some PII (personally identifiable information) being stored, such as the Date of Birth along with the name and a few other fields. I want to encrypt the data with AES_ENCRYPT using CBC on MySQL, however there is an administrator who needs to see the information, but if I encrypt the user's information, the administrator won't be able to see. Should I encrypt the PII with the username and have the administrator not be able to see and encrypt the username with the username, or should I leave the username unencrypted but encrypt everything else with the username, leaving some security risks, but allowing the administrator to see the information. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, encrypting data at rest in DBMSs with symmetric encryption like AES is both unnecessary and insufficient to protect it from attack.

Why?

For one thing, the weak link in a system like this is typically the web server, not the MySQL server machine. But the web server must contain the necessary key to both encrypt and decrypt the data. If an attacker pwns your web server, he takes possession of your key and your algorithms to generate keys, and therefore he pwns your sensitive data. He also has a really robust way to figure out what data you think is sensitive.

It's much less likely the attacker will be able to compromise your MySQL server directly; in situations involving PII those machines ordinarily live behind firewalls.

For another thing:  your administrator. He will need to have possession of the key, and administrators are juicy targets for attackers. (I'm not saying he's a black hat, just that his white hat has a big red target on it.)

Another thing: it may give you a false sense of security.

(Notice that passwords are not encrypted: they are hashed. It's simple to compare a password to a hashed password and say "match" or "no match." But it's much harder to take a hashed password and recover the original one. So the argument that passwords are "encrypted" isn't relevant to this situation.)

I seriously suggest you spend your time and money **not** on encrypting your PII at rest as you suggest. Instead spend your resources to make sure your web site is secure, and making sure your MySQL server is safely behind a robust firewall and invisible to the public internet.

Look at the [OWASP Top Ten](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2017-Top_10) vulnerabilities. Spend time dealing with them on your site. Use a penetration test tool like burp scan or zap scan to try to break in.

Securing your web site is like the old joke about the two guys and the bear.

Bear:  roar.

Joe: I hope I can outrun the bear.

Mike: I just have to outrun you.

In cybersecurity, you don't want to be Joe.